# why is that making GET request with search param won't return 404 even when the no resources have been found

Tags: javascript, http, frontend

I encountered this weird problem when experimenting with JavaScript's URL object

here is the demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-wilbur-15kyt?file=/src/index.js

so the endpoint is https://jsonplaceholsdsdsdder.typicode.com/todos/,

The key `id` can be integer as its value. So https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?id=4 is valid. and https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?id=dsdsd is not valid.

I found that using `Fetch` to make the request `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?id=4` will still return a response with a status code `200`.

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector("#input");

const endpoint = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/");
inputEl.addEventListener("input", async e => {
  const { value: text } = e.target;
  endpoint.searchParams.set("id", text);
  const repsonse = await fetch(endpoint).catch(console.error);
  const data = await repsonse.json();
  console.log(repsonse.status); // 200
  console.log(data); // []
});
```

However if we construct the URL directly like this 
`https://jsonplaceholsdsdsdder.typicode.com/todos/dd`. this will actually return a response with 404 status code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I personally don't understand your actual question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way the API works server side.

If you try and use that route, you'll get the `404` error because that specific route wasn't found.

If you use the `searchParams.set` method, it's just a parameter that the backend will use to filter the full list of todos, in which case the call was made successfully, hence the `200` response code. but the response results were empty, hence the empty array `[]`.

Comment: You're welcome :) It had me stumped too when I encountered stuff like that. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Hi I have a follow up question. So if `https://jsonplaceholsdsdsdder.typicode.com/todos/dd` will not fail `fetch`, but it just returns a valid `response` with `404` status code. and if we mess up the URL completely, like` https://#$#$#$#$.typicode.com/todos/dd`, `fetch` will flat out fail and reject. I wonder what is the proper term or wording to describe these two errors? The first situation is that we are visiting a ninvalid resource location that jsonplaceholder.com has not exposed a resource with that path. What about the latter?

Comment: Rey Green's answer covers this quite well.

Answer (score 2):

search params are not a part of the resource location. They are optional and have to be manually accessed by the server processing the request.

**https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/** is a valid resource location that has been set up by jsonplaceholder.com.

**https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?id=4** is a valid resource location because anything after the question mark (?) is a parameter and parameters are not considered to be apart of the resource location so it is still valid.

**https://jsonplaceholsdsdsdder.typicode.com/todos/dd** is not a valid resource location because jsonplaceholder.com has not exposed a resource with that path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So  we are visiting an invalid resource location that jsonplaceholder.com has not exposed a resource with that path if we are getting a 404. Then what is the proper way to describe the situation where we mess up the URL completely, like` https://#$#$#$#$.typicode.com/todos/dd` and the `fetch` request will straight up fail.

Comment: firstly, #$#$#$#$$ is not a valid subdomain name because it has special characters.
so, it could be the request itself is seen as invalid.

Answer (score 0):

for this code id is printed as we passed params
but if you write like this
async function getData({id})
it shows undefined
to solve this type of problem passed id params without {} braces